# How do I solve an LP problem when constraints have different inequalities?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

How can I solve this LP problem?

Maximize $p=x$ subject to

$x+y \leq 30$

$x-2y \leq 0$

$2x+y \geq 30$

$x\geq 0 , y\geq 0$

using the simplex method?

Comment: use the 2-phase simplex method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you are asking how to write the LP in 'standard form'?

The general idea here is if you have a constraint of the form $a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_n x_n \leq 0$, then you replace this constraint by an equality constraint of the form $a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_n x_n = -s$, where $s$ is a new variable (called a slack variable) with the constraint $s \geq 0$. It is easy to see that these are equivalent (as long as you now optimize over the new variables as well).

So, your problem would become:

Maximize p=x subject to :

$$x+y = 30-s_1$$

$$x-2y = -s_2$$

$$2x+y = 30+s_3$$

$$x \geq 0 , y\geq 0$$
$$s_1 \geq 0 , s_2\geq 0, s_3 \geq 0$$

Comment: But should I add an artificial variable to `2x+y >=30` ? 
something like  `2x+y - s3 + Z1 =30` ?

Comment: No. The $s_3$ slack variable already allows you to replace the $\geq$ by $=$. Note the sign on $s_3$, which is different to the sign on $s_1, s_2$.

Comment: aha , I see, thanks:)